# How to stop/invalidate NStimer

Tags: iphone, ipad, nstimer

I am using

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f
                                  target:self
                                selector:@selector(update)
                                userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];
```

I want to stop calling this timer one.

```
viewDidDisappear
```

How can i do that? invalidate?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Declare  `NSTimer *myTimer` in .h file.

Assign instance as tom said like this

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(update)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

Stop and Invalidate using this

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: Is the nil required? Or just trying to clean up the memory actively?

Comment: I get the memory, but why is it required?

Comment: For timers, there is no release method. By making it nil we assure to free memory utilized by the object. Hope I have answered satisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

viewController .h

```
 NSTimer *timer;
```

viewcontroller.m

```
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(pollTime)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];


  - (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
    {
      [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
      [timer invalidate];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use the `- (void)invalidate` instance method of `NSTimer`.

Of course, to do that, you would have to save the `NSTimer` instance returned from `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]` into an ivar or property of your view controller, so you can access it in `viewDidDisappear`.

Answer (score 1):

`invalidate` Method of `NSTimer` is use for stop timer

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
}
```

If you are not ARC then don't forget `[self.timer release];`

Answer (score 1):

For stopping or invalidating NSTimer first you have to create instance for NSTimer in Globally.

```
 Timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f
                                  target:self
                                selector:@selector(update)
                                userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];
```

after that try like this,

```
if (Timer != nil) {

            [Timer invalidate];
            Timer = nil;

        }
```