# Playing Parts of an Audio File in iOS issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, avaudioplayer

Is it possible to play parts of an audio file. So, i have one audio file with a lot of sounds. In this case, the One audio file is acting like an "ARRAY", holding many items. I want to separate parts of the audio by playing at `{5:01 and stop at 6:08}` something like that. Is this possible? I am very knew to Xcode, so this might be a dumb question. Thanks. If there is anything you need, please comment below.

Comment: This is not relatd to xcode, which is an IDE.

Comment: It's definitely possible, since I've done it.  I don't have the code at hand, though.  Something like Murali's code, IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing audio for certain duration is not available..But we can do this in following way.

```
-(void)Play
{
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[FileDetailsRec valueForKey:@"Path"]] error:nil];
    [avPlayer setCurrentTime:5.01f];
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];
    objTimer = [NSTimer  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.07f target:self selector:@selector(stop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)stop
{ 
    [objTimer invalidate];
    [avPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Is there a way to reset the timer?

Comment: Take an object for NsTimer and then in stop method just place this [objTimer invalidate]; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170518/how-to-stop-invalidate-nstimer

Answer (score 2):

this one might be possible by Using AVAudioPlayer but i'm not sure about this one once see this reference class
   [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)  
  in this class bu using below method you can get your requirement

```
- (BOOL)playAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time  and for stoping use NSTimer like


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(place your time interval)
                                  target:self
                                selector:@selector(stop)
                                userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:NO];
```